# Correct time conversion

Tags: .net, vb.net

I am receiving a time recorded in the continent of 13:00 as the timezone is utc+2 and I am in the UK and my output is expected in utc I am converting the time to 12:00 and the recipient is saying that it should be 11:00! What is the correct time to send? I am using this code to convert the Datetime:

```
Dim currentUTC As DateTime = localZone.ToUniversalTime(03/10/2018 13:00)
Dim truedate As DateTime = currentUTC
```

Comment: This is confusing to read. Can you clean it up a bit?

Comment: This isnt C#, its VB

Comment: What is `localZone` and how do you set it up?

Comment: How exactly are you receiving the recorded time? Is it in a text file, via a database, or something else?

Comment: Note that in VB, #03/10/2018 13:00# is the date literal for the 10th of March, not the 3rd of October. In central Europe, the 10th of March 2018 is in UTC+1 ("Winter time"), whereas the 3rd of October 2018 is in UTC+2 ("Daylight Savings Time").

Answer (score 0):

11:00 AM is correct. ie:

```
void Main()
{
    DateTime t;
    DateTime.TryParse("2018/10/03T13:00:00+02:00", out t);
    Console.WriteLine(t.ToUniversalTime());
}
```

EDIT: You removed the C# tag, then:

```
Sub Main
    Dim t As DateTime
    DateTime.TryParse("2018/10/03T13:00:00+02:00", t)
    Console.WriteLine(t.ToUniversalTime())
End Sub
```

Comment: Thanks for the replies I included the c# tag on purpose, in the hope that some c# guru might provide an answer!  I am not receiving the time in the format "2018/10/03T13:00:00+02:00" it is in the format "2018/10/03T13:00:00"! How do I deal with it?

Comment: I am receiving the time from a web service?

Comment: @joebohen, that format is unspecified. You can convert to local or universal, you need to know which one.

Comment: The time is expected in utc.

Comment: @joebohen How do you know that the timezone is utc+2 ? Will it always be that? You could append "+2:00" to the string before parsing it.

Comment: @joebohen, if the time is known to be UTC then you can convert it to LocalTime (if zone is +2 ToLocalTime would return 15:00, not 10:00 or 11:00 - IOW +2 is 2 hrs ahead of your location, UK)